# Chromecast support HLS

Tags: android, streaming, chromecast

Есть приложение в которым у меня прекрасно работают *hls*. Пришла идея транслировать этот поток на Chromecast.

Начал читать документацию и смотреть туториалы - закралось подозрение что hls без кастомного *Reciever* не работает.

Вопрос в следующем, верно ли выше сказанное, и это означает что мне нужен аккаунт для *chromecast app*(5 баксов стоит)?

Если кто сталкивался, подтвердите. На Википедии нашел такое предложение:

For example, a simple receiver app might just play HTML5 content, whereas custom receiver apps, which require more programming effort, can take a variety of streaming protocols, including MPEG-DASH, HTTP Live Streaming, and the Microsoft Smooth Streaming Protocol.

Comment: вы уверены, что ваш вопрос имеет отношение к Android?

Comment: Точно, я буду стримить с android устройства(с написанного приложения). Меток типа 'google-cast','chromecast' или других более походящих я не нашел. Тем более в приложения хромкаст часто встречается. Поэтому я и поставил метку.

Comment: я добавил вам метку `chromecast`.

Comment: android мне удалить, так как это лишь частный случай?

Comment: Я не знаю, оставьте пока. Я честно сказать, почти не понял вашего вопроса, а с вопросами по Android такое бывает крайне редко...

Comment: Как я понял в схеме работы chromecast есть отправитель и приемник. Приемник по умолчанию ловит только некоторые форматы видео. А чтобы он смог воспроизводить hls нужно кастомизировать приемник. Кастомизация доступна только после специальной регстрации. Но у меня плохо с английским и я боюсь, что где то что то упустил.